# Twitter stream API request - don't follow certain users

Tags: twitter, request, twitter-follow

I don't want to receives tweets from certain users. Twitter [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters) mentions about "follow" param, but I need inversion of this option. Is there any other option than filtering it on the side of my app?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to "invert" the follow parameter? The follow parameter does exactly what you are asking for i.e. you give it a list of certain users, and it delivers the Tweets from them (not from others). Can you give an example why that does not work?

Comment: I would like to receive all tweets from twitter stream with given terms, except these written by users excluded by me.

For example: 
All tweets with phrase "donald trump", except these written by @realdonaldtrump.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis-read your question. That's very clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Twitter streaming API filter options do not allow you to exclude results from the filter pattern - it is inclusive. The enterprise PowerTrack API does have the ability to [exclude terms and users as part of the filter pattern](http://support.gnip.com/apis/powertrack/rules.html), but it is commercial.

You will have to filter the results in your own code. You could do this by looking for the presence of the user object belonging to the user you want to exclude, and ignoring those Tweets.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to see `tweets` from specific users  on your `timeline` you can simply `mute` those users. Muting just turn off their tweets from your timeline and the he/she will still remain in your following list.

If you are looking to do this via `Twitter API` here is the reference link
    https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/mutes/users/create

And if you want to mute users from Desktop or Mobile you can click on Down Arrow icon and select **Mute @username**.
[image: On Desktop you can click on down arrow key and select Mute @username.]

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's very useful knowledge. However this doesn't solve my problem, cause I need mute option in **Twitter streaming API**. Have you maybe heard/seen something about that kind of option in streaming API? I can't find anything in this kind in the documentation.